# Best technology for client-server Android App

Tags: android, multiplayer

I need to make for school an app that runs on Android. Actually there are two apps, a client and a server. Ther server runs on a PC while the clients run on Android devices. I want to know what is the best technology for this. I know RMI and WebServices are not implemented in Android so what are the alternatives (besides actually communicating with sockets in the traditional way). One alternative that I did not look into is REST, but I will need to be able to notify a client once another client has done something, similar to turn base games where Player A notifies Player B that he made his move. 
Like I said, sockets do the trick, but are little low-level compared to RMI and WebServices and only want to use those as a last resort.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple. Use REST and have the clients poll for updates.

Also, if you get to a point down the road where you need to scale, this solution is actually fairly easy to scale because your servers do not need to maintain connections. Since there is no shared state between a particular server and the client (there is shared server between the *application* and the client), you can easily add more servers to handle the polling and put them behind a load balancer.

You can also add in caching so that the polling just gets the exact same response without causing a re-compute of the response. You would then be able to have the back-end game-state servers update the caches when the game state changes. This would let you poll much more frequently and still have a very flexible, scalable architecture.

Comment: Using rest I will have one user in an infinite loop of "checking if the other player has made his move". This is rather CPU intensive and also will do a lot more requests on the server. Another problem is that I may need for the two users to communicate via peer2peer once a "game room" has been set up.

Comment: Nice explanation buddy.Can you share some link to know this thing ?

Comment: @Pazvanti - With any polling set up, you always need to have some sort of interval between polls. You can't just throw it into a loop without some sort of wait in there. The client-to-client communication can also be done through the server infrastructure. Depending on how responsive you want things to be, you can adjust the polling times appropriately.

Comment: @Dharmendra - Unfortunately, I don't have any sources for this idea at the moment. I had a similar scenario (not with an Android app, but similar requirements), and this was the architecture we ended up with. The main idea is that you are keeping all layers as loosely coupled as possible, keeping as little state in the transactions as you can, and layering things so you can scale out when needed. All basic scaleability principles.

Comment: @Pazvanti - Also, once you begin to scale, the large number of server hits does go up, but the caching layer takes most of that pain away, so that the server calls don't impact your application's processing. The app is just dealing with updates to the game state and telling the cache it was updated. The clients only deal with the cache, which will be a very fast operation, since it already has the  answer to the question they are asking and just has to look it up, rather than calculate it.

Answer (score 2):

For a turn-based game you can take a look at XMPP (e.g. [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/)) that is traditionally used for instant messaging. It would also be interesting to create a game using [C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) that is used for push notifications.

You can also look into HTTP streaming which is essentially an unending HTTP response in which player moves are fed into.

Alternatively you can look into binary messaging systems that are more suited for real-time games but still applicable such as [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) (what's wrong with a smooth turn-based game?).

Comment: The problem with HTTP streaming, especially in a turn-based game scenario, is that the server has to maintain that connection state, and in this case, 2 connections per game. With most web servers (not all), open connections are very memory intensive, which means that this approach won't scale particularly well, since most of the time is spent waiting on the user and wasting resources.

Comment: You're right - HTTP streaming doesn't look scalable. Use of C2DM would be a very nice solution though.

Comment: I will have to look into Smack and see what I can do with it. If it is mostly used for instant messaging than it may not be the best solution...still, it may be more powerful than that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Depends on your game. In a lot of turn-based games there isn't much difference between sending chat messages and game messages between clients. My favourite is still C2DM though!

Comment: I've never used C2DM, so I'm not sure how well it would work in practice (specifically, what the latency is on clients receiving the message), but it might work very well for certain types of games. Especially ones where the "turn" could be a very long time (hours or more, rather than minutes)

Comment: From experience it takes seconds - but I don't know how that will change over time given that more people are adopting it (you put yourself in Google's hands).

Comment: If your data being transferred is easily sent as XML, then XMPP can be easily used to accomplish this.  You need to accomplish client to client communications, which is what XMPP is designed for.  The messages themselves are easily extendable which makes it easy to create and consume custom message content.